# Using a G. 655 with a G. 652.D fiber cable?

Tags: fiber, cabling, optics

Is it possible to use a G.652.D with a G.655 fiber for just a small distance (less than 10 m) for the interconnect only (from the patch panel to the switch) ? If yes or no, what will happen ?

And for long distance, its not possible and it will not work, because of the IOR will be different right ? or because another thing ?

Best Regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

It will work.  You will get more loss at the splice than if you were splicing like fiber but you can do it.  You can even mix the fiber types in longer runs.

Reference:  [Mixing of G655 and G652 Fibers in a Network](http://www.sterliteoptical.com/pdf/Knowledgecenter/Mixing%20of%20G655%20and%20G652%20Optical%20Fibers.pdf)